# How to install caret package in R version 3.6.3

Tags: r, caret, failed-installation

I try to install the package "caret" inside the R software version 3.6.3. I used the follow script:

install.packages ('caret',dependencies=c('Depends','Suggests')

Inside the Console, appeared this message: " Installing package into "C:/......" (as. 'lib' is unspecified). Warning in istall.packages: dependencies 'fastICA', 'randomForest' are not available. Also installing the dependencies 'modeldata', 'themis'. Appear the question "Do you want to install from sources the package which need compilation?" I choose Yes.
If after the instalaltion I run the library caret, the load failed. I did not understand where is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to install `'fastICA', 'randomForest'` beforehand?

Comment: When asked, `"Do you want to install from sources the package which need compilation?"` always choose no unless you know what you are doing. When choosing yes, the package will be compiled, when choosing no it will just be installed. You might end up with a slightly older version, but there is a far smaller chance that the installation fails.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information, but in final I try to install the package for the R version 4.1.3 and I installed the package without problem. I don't understand why for the previous version I have this problem. But thanks so much for all your answers.